# Spark Streaming from existing RDD

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Anyone please  help me out how to create a DStream from existing RDD.
My code is :

```
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> rddd = ctx.parallelize(arraylist);
```

Now i need to use these **rddd** as input to **JavaStreamingContext**.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? It is unusual to just create stream from RDD because RDD is a finite set of data, while streaming normally implies continuous data processing.

Comment: If you want to test things and have a DStream that at each iteration returns the same RDD, you could use http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ConstantInputDStream but you didn't tell us exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: Hello @AlexLarikov and @ Roberto Congiu .. Thank you for your quick response. My project requirement is for every 15 mints new xml files are pushed into aws s3 server and then these files parsed and stored into some arraylist. now i have to store arraylist into cassandra database. Presently my code is in spark core, but problem i have to run the code for every 15 mins to store the arraylist into db...That's why iam looking for Spark Streaming

Comment: there is `fileStream` available for this purpose to monitor directory and stream files from there

Comment: Hello Alex.. Thank you for your response.
can you provide documentation for fileStream if possible?

Answer (score 2):

Have a try [queueStream](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.html#queueStream(scala.collection.mutable.Queue,%20boolean,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) API.
Queue of RDDs as a Stream, each RDD pushed into the queue will be treated as a batch of data in the DStream, and processed like a stream.

```
public <T> InputDStream<T> queueStream(scala.collection.mutable.Queue<RDD<T>> queue,
                              boolean oneAtATime,
                              scala.reflect.ClassTag<T> evidence$15)

Create an input stream from a queue of RDDs. In each batch, it will process either one or all of the RDDs returned by the queue.
NOTE: Arbitrary RDDs can be added to queueStream, there is no way to recover data of those RDDs, so queueStream doesn't support checkpointing.
```